# Zend Validate: How to validate each separate value in comma separated values in textarea for zend_validate_DbRecordExist?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-validate

I have text box in which your adds values in comma separated values. Once the form is post I want to check each of CSV value against database table that if each one of them exist already. If so then I want to throw error message otherwise that is fine.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a **custom validator**. you can either do it extending `Zend_Validate_Abstract` or you can simply use a **callback validator**.

To do so, you need to add this to your element:

```
$elem = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('elem_name');
$elem->setLabel('Label Name:')
         ->setRequired(true)
         ->addValidator('callback', true, array('callback' => array($this, 'functionName')));
$this->addElement($elem);
```

And in the same class (usually your form is in a class that extends Zend_Form), you add this method:

```
public function functionName($csvString) {
    // stuff here using explode(',', $csvString)
    // foreach() to iterate over the result and match against the db each $value
}
```

See [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for more information.

However, if your form element is going to be called more than once, and in different forms, then I don't recommend you to use a callback, but you'd better write your own validator, the theory remains the same though. [Take a look here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html) for more information about how to write validators.

Comment: Your answer is perfect but in my case I need to extract all invalid comma separated values and show all these values as in error as below text area element. So by the method you suggested i can return only true or false for callback validator but can not collect invalid values. So what i did finally is once validating form using $form->isValid($_POST) I explode values and check separately of they are in database I collect then all and generate error msg using $element->addError($invalid_csv.' are invalid');

Answer (score 2):

I really doubt that this can be achieved directly just using Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists. I think the best solution would be to create a custom validator for this purpose. Something that would take your value then explode it based on a , `$valueArray = explode(',', $value);` and then for each $valueArray check if the element exists in the db. This shouldn't be too hard. If you dont have idea about custom validators [this](http://mnshankar.wordpress.com/2010/02/27/custom-validators-in-zend-form/) might be helpful.